# Lubuntu 16.04: Get Shown GNU GRUB 2. Can't find Boot Drives. Computer is dual booted with Windows 10 Education Edition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu

So, I'm trying to boot into Lubuntu 16.04, but I get shown the GNU GRUB screen. I can't find my boot files either, as the closest thing I can find is on my hd0,gpt2 partition is "efi/ _SMSTVolumeID.7159644d-f741-ab29-0ad8aa4771ca" I had a Micro SD card in my computer, and when I last shut down my computer, I took out the MicroSD too early and then forced shut down on the computer, thinking I had an error with my computer. I have tried LS, and none of the partitions show my boot files. Is there anything I can do? Or is it too late, and would I have to reinstall Lubuntu 16.04?

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: I'd boot a 'live' system and `fsck` your partitions to ensure they are all clean (esp. the removed partition(s) on the SD card you mentioned).  If that file-system is unclean & relates to the required partition, you'll have your issue (which will be fixed when fs clean). I'd also consider moving to a supported release of Lubuntu.